# Why can't GetType() find types when invoked through a method group delegate?

Tags: c#, reflection

We have a very simple program invoking the `Type.GetType` static method. Both examples should return a valid type instance. Only the second one actually is. Looks like something odd is happening with the stack crawl used by `GetType`, but what exactly is the issue here? Is it bug or some obscure feature?

```
public class TestClass { }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var fullName = typeof(TestClass).FullName;
        Console.WriteLine("Full name: {0}", fullName);

        new[] { fullName }.Select(Type.GetType).ToList().ForEach(t => Console.WriteLine("Method group: '{0}'", t));
        new[] { fullName }.Select(t => Type.GetType(t)).ToList().ForEach(t => Console.WriteLine("Closure: '{0}'", t));
    }
}
```

Running:

```
Full name: GetTypeBeingWeird.TestClass
Method group: ''
Closure: 'GetTypeBeingWeird.TestClass'
```

Comment: May be I should close the older one? Not sure, welcoming opinions on this...

Answer (score 165, accepted):

This is really interesting. It's a mixture of the behaviour of `Type.GetType(string)` in terms of the calling assembly, and how method group conversions work.

First, the [`Type.GetType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation includes this:

> If *typeName* includes the namespace but not the assembly name, this method searches only the calling object's assembly and Mscorlib.dll, in that order.

In your first call, you're passing in a delegate which calls `Type.GetType`... but it isn't particularly called from your assembly. It's effectively called *directly* from the `Select` method in LINQ... if you looked at the stack trace from within `Type.GetType`, you'd see `Select` as the direct caller, I believe.

In your second call, you're passing in a closure which calls `Type.GetType`, and that call is within your assembly.

That's why it finds the type in the second case but not the first. This is further validated by specifying a type which is in the LINQ assembly:

```
var fullName = typeof(Enumerable).FullName;
```

Then the results are the opposite way round:

```
Full name: System.Linq.Enumerable
Method group: 'System.Linq.Enumerable'
Closure: ''
```

If you specify something in mscorlib (e.g. `typeof(string).FullName`) then both approaches work:

```
Full name: System.String
Method group: 'System.String'
Closure: 'System.String'
```

The way to get around this oddity when looking for your class, still using a method group, is simply to supply the assembly-qualified name instead:

```
var fullName = typeof(TestClass).AssemblyQualifiedName;
```

Comment: Wow, using the calling assembly as a hidden input is hideous. Fun bug, though.

Comment: Use of calling assembly instead of entry or executing as default may be (and I am sure is indeed) a deliberate decision. One reason I can think of is to avoid type spoofing in mscorelib calls to Type.GetType() if entry/executing assembly has declared same namespace and type name matching mscorelib's. One man's "hideos" is another man's not having his ass handed back to him via std library hijacking.

Comment: The API should not take *any* assembly as a hidden input. It should be specified by the caller. Using the entry assembly would be almost as bad. A type name without an assembly name is simply ambiguous. There is no good disambiguation strategy possible.

Comment: @Jon did you really mean ? ``That's why it finds the type in the first case but not the second`` or you mean was : ``second case but not the first``, i am confused

Comment: @EʜsᴀɴSᴀᴊᴊᴀᴅ: Yes, I did. Fixed now, thanks.

Comment: so this approach : ``.Select(Type.GetType).ToList()`` should be avoided right?

Comment: @EʜsᴀɴSᴀᴊᴊᴀᴅ: For this particular call, *if you're only specifying a namespace-qualified type name*, yes. For most methods, which don't care about the calling assembly, or if you're specifying an assembly-qualified name, it's fine.